Svelte 5: Passing state and derived values from children to parent (runes mode without stores)
I have a parent component with multiple draggable Item-components which will be created dynamically in the final app. Inside each Item I calculate the current position as well as a derived offset value. Each time, any Item is dragged I want its position/offset to be shared reactively with the parent component.
In Svelte 4 with stores this was fairly easy. However, I struggle implementing this in Svelte 5 with runes. Context-API somehow isn't an option, since I'd like to define pos/offset inside the Item-component where they belong... shouldn't I?
The current code has two issues:

(1) While sending the position (state) to the parent via bound props, this does not work for the offset (derived). Why?
(2) As soon as the second item-component is mounted, the connection between the first item and the parent is lost. Why?

Update 2024-05-14
Here is a reduced verison of my code (REPL):
App.svelte
<svelte:options runes="{true}" />

<script>
    import Item from './Item.svelte';

    let CURRENT = $state({pos: {x:99, y:99}, offset: 99});

</script>

<h1>Last dragged item: ({CURRENT.pos.x} / {CURRENT.pos.y}) Offset: {CURRENT.offset}</h1>

<Item bind:CURRENT={CURRENT} itemName='ONE' />
<Item bind:CURRENT={CURRENT} itemName='TWO' />

Item.svelte
<svelte:options runes="{true}" />

<script>
    import interact from 'interactjs';

    let { CURRENT = $bindable(), itemName } = $props();
    let item;
    
    let pos = $state({x:0, y:0});
    let offset = $derived(Math.floor(Math.sqrt( Math.pow(pos.x,2) + Math.pow(pos.y,2) )));

    CURRENT.pos = pos;
    CURRENT.offset = offset;

    const handleDraggable = (node) => {
        interact(node).draggable({              
            onmove: (ev) => {
                let el = ev.target;
        
                let x = (parseFloat(el.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + ev.dx;
                let y = (parseFloat(el.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + ev.dy;
                
                el.style.webkitTransform =  el.style.transform = `translate(${x}px,${y}px)`;
                el.setAttribute('data-x', x);
                el.setAttribute('data-y', y);
                pos.x = x;
                pos.y = y;
            },
        });
    }
</script>


<div id="draggable" bind:this={item} use:handleDraggable> 
    <p>{itemName} ({pos.x} / {pos.y}) Offset: {offset}</p>
</div>


The recommended way to pass info from parent to child is by using props, and from child to parent is by using events (in Svelte 4) and callback props (in Svelte 5). I think using that will solve your problem.

Include all relevant code in the question, remove anything irrelevant first or start from scratch to make the reproduction minimal.

I have just updated my question including some reduced code.

@PeppeL-G: Thank you! Which part exactly would you pass as a callback prop?

A function that receives the new position of the item each time it has been moved, for example: <Item onDragged={ (pos) => { CURRENT.pos = pos } } />. Then in your child component you need to call the onDragged() props and pass it the new position each time it has been dragged a little. You can also include the computed offset if you want.

Oh wow, this is such a nice way to solve this problem! Thank you so much for showing me, @PeppeL-G! I'll update the question with a working REPL.

@The_Lab, write and accept your own answer to the question instead of writing it in your question :)

@PeppeL-G, oh, ok, I can do so. Was not sure how to handle this situation, since it's you who deserves the credits.

Thanks for the thought, but no problem ^^

As hinted by @PeppeL-G in the comments to my question, variables can be passed from children to parent using callback props:

The recommended way to pass info from parent to child is by using props, and from child to parent is by using events (in Svelte 4) and callback props (in Svelte 5). I think using that will solve your problem.

Here is the changed code and a REPL
App.svelte
<svelte:options runes="{true}" />

<script>
    import Item from './Item.svelte';
    
    let CURRENT = $state({pos: {x:99, y:99}, offset: 99});
    let onDragged = (pos, offset) => { 
        CURRENT.pos = pos, 
        CURRENT.offset = offset
    }
</script>

<h1>Last dragged item: ({CURRENT.pos.x} / {CURRENT.pos.y}) Offset: {CURRENT.offset}</h1>

<Item itemName='ONE' {onDragged} } />
<Item itemName='TWO' {onDragged} } />

Item.svelte
<svelte:options runes="{true}" />

<script>
        import interact from 'interactjs';

    //let { CURRENT = $bindable(), itemName } = $props();
    let { itemName, onDragged } = $props();
    let item;
    
    let pos = $state({x:0, y:0});
    let offset = $derived(Math.floor(Math.sqrt( Math.pow(pos.x,2) + Math.pow(pos.y,2) )));

    const handleDraggable = (node) => {
            interact(node).draggable({              
                onmove: (ev) => {
                    let el = ev.target;
        
                    let x = (parseFloat(el.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + ev.dx;
                    let y = (parseFloat(el.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + ev.dy;
                
                    el.style.webkitTransform =  el.style.transform = `translate(${x}px,${y}px)`;
                    el.setAttribute('data-x', x);
                    el.setAttribute('data-y', y);
                    pos.x = x;
                    pos.y = y;
                                onDragged(pos, offset);
                },
            });
        }
</script>


<div id="draggable" bind:this={item} use:handleDraggable> 
    <p>{itemName} ({pos.x} / {pos.y}) Offset: {offset}</p>
</div>


<style>
    #draggable {
        background-color: green;
          width: 220px;
    }
</style>

